# Magento Restful Api, Creating a virtual product

Tags: magento-1.9, api, rest-api

Finally gotten our Restful API working with our third-party app, and of course bumped into what may become a very stressful headache.

**How do I go about allowing API Virtual Product Creation?**

When I went to go create a virtual product, using the following json...

```
{  
   "type_id":"virtual",
   "attribute_set_id":4,
   "sku":"api-order-json",
   "status":1,
   "visibility":1,
   "name":"Api Virtual Product",
   "description":"Simple Description",
   "short_description":"Simple Short Description",
   "price":125,
   "tax_class_id":0
}
```

I get the lovely return statement "Creation of products with type 'virtual' is not implemented", which is a huge dream killer. As all of our needed products are virtual.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the only way is to implement custom API on Magento side similar to this one `\Mage_Catalog_Model_Api2_Product_Rest_Admin_V1::_create` but for virtual products. This would be not trivial task.